# SetParent: Window reacts slow when getting focus

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the SetParent function of the Windows API. I'm using it to inject one of my windows into the Window of an external application (like Notepad). My Window contains an EditWindow as Child Window and a few buttons, nothing more. I use something like this:

```
long style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
style |= WS_CHILD;
style &= ~WS_POPUP;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
SetParent(hwnd, newParent);
```

This works, however if I click from outside of the external application into the textbox, it takes several *seconds* until it gets the focus. In the meantime nothing happens, even with Spy++ I can't catch any messages within this delay.

The strange thing is also that this only seems to happen with my specific application (its some very old and special measurement software), with notepad for example the delay does not happen.

So, here is my question: What could potentialy cause this problem? Are there cases where SetParent could cause such a behaviour?

Greets,
cpp_beginner

Comment: Let me just quote `The Old New Thing` here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx which has the following: `Is it technically legal to have a parent/child or owner/owned relationship between windows from different processes? Yes, it is technically legal. It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws.` Most likely the delay you're seeing is related to the mentioned attachment of input queues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I already knew this article (I found it when searching via google for answers to this problem).

I know that it has somehow to do with the windows not communicating correctly, but how can I find out whats really causing the problem? I already know that it is possible to do that for this application, because somebody already did that for this application...

Comment: It certainly relates to the innards of your external application (which is other than Notepad). It can, for example, recalculate child windows positions when you inject the new child, or do something more. In any case I'd not blame the `SetParent` function in this slowdown.

Comment: Ok, and is there any possiblity of telling the window of this external application to "ignore" this child window so that it doesn't send any messages to it?

I just want to have my edit window embedded into the other application, the moving and sizing could be done manually by me as I already hooked into the process of the application with the use of a dll...